# How to prevent files from opening in the same instance of VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code

If I have a VS Code window open, and I double-click a file in the file explorer, it opens as a new tab in the same window. This is frustrating if the existing window is for a project and the newly opened file is unrelated. How do I force double-clicked files in the file explorer to open in a new instance of VS Code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Go to `Settings > Window > NewWindow.`

Turn `on` 'open files in New Window' option.

Comment: Thank you so much, this has been bothering me for years